# AngularJS: How to change radio button view when model changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the `HTML` as

```
<div class="btn-group col-lg-3" data-toggle="buttons" data-ng-model="transaction.debit" required>
    <label class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="setDebitTransaction('true')">
      <input type="radio">Debit
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="setDebitTransaction('false')">
      <input type="radio">Credit
    </label>

<div>
```

and my `Controller` looks like

```
$scope.transaction = {};
  $scope.setDebitTransaction = function(value) {
    $scope.transaction.debit = value;
    console.log('Debit = ', $scope.transaction.debit);
  };
```

**What I want?**
- When I click on radio button I see that the `$scope.transaction.debit` is correctly set and that the corresponding radio button is enabled
- But when my model changes its value from backend processing, I see that `$scope.transaction.debit` is correctly set but **corresponding radio element is not enabled**

**Question**
- How can I **enable** the radio button based on value in `$scope.transaction.debit`?

**DEMO**

I have put this on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ONiCogHcIfjQBxPEFuGB?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you are trying to do is get the appropriate button in the btn-group to change its state to "active" (bootstrap style class). To do this, there are probably a million ways, here is one:

Use the `ng-class` directive in angular, to inject a class to the btn div, based on some `$scope` attribute (in your case `$scope.transaction.debit`).

Here is how that might look in code:

```
<label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active': transaction.debit}" data-ng-click="setDebitTransaction('true')">
  <input type="radio">Debit
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active': !transaction.debit}" data-ng-click="setDebitTransaction('false')">
  <input type="radio">Credit
</label>
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0jc73SohTci9MAL3D57?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Set the `active` class via `ng-class` on your labels like so:

```
<label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active: transaction.debit}" data-ng-click="setDebitTransaction('true')">
      <input type="radio">Debit
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active: !transaction.debit}" data-ng-click="setDebitTransaction('false')">
      <input type="radio">Credit
</label>
```

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tUzF4J9ixEnKxLNdI1Bm